# Running two Javascript functions in the onclick event of a button

Tags: javascript, jsp, events

I am developing an application with Struts and jsp on a page I want to run Javascript 2 functions in the onclick event of a button How do I do? I've tried to separate the functions with a semicolon.

Comment: Show what you've tried... you should just be able to call them `func1(); func2();`

Comment: onclick="function1();function2()"

Comment: yep, looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the click event, call both functions.

**Javascript**

```
<button onclick="function1(); function2();"></button>
```

Comment: That's why I included the vanilla Javascript to the answer.

Comment: Yeah I see that - just get rid of the jQuery - it's useless, especially in a question like this.